# How to solve simultaeous equations with same unknown values on lhs and rhs?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to solve the following system of equations for $f(0)$

\begin{align*}
f(0)  & = 1+ f(1)\\
f(1)  & = \frac{1}{3}+ \frac{2}{3}(f(2)+1)\\
f(2)  & = \frac{2}{3}(f(1)+1)+ \frac{1}{3}(f(3)+1)\\
f(3)  & = 1+ f(2)\\
\end{align*}

The problem is if you substitute f(2) into f(1) then there is also an expression with f(3) which if you sub this in as well gives you another expression with f(2) and if you sub this in as well the pattern repeats and the calculation becomes recursive.

Clearly this is not the way to proceed, but I'm totally stuck as to how to tackle a problem like this?

If you let $w = f(0), x = f(1), y = f(2), z = f(3)$ and rewrote the equations as

$$\begin{align} w - x &= 1\\3x - 2y &= 3\\3y - 2x - z &= 3\\z - y &=1\end{align}$$

OK so

from eq 4

$z=1+y$

sub into 3

$3y-2x-(y+1)=3$
$2y-2x=4$
$2y=2x+4$

sub into eq 2

$3x-(2x+4)=3$
$x-4=3$
$x=7$

sub into 1

$w-7=1$
$w=8$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let $w = f(0), x = f(1), y = f(2), z = f(3)$ and rewrote the equations as

$$\begin{align} w - x &= 1\\3x - 2y &= 3\\3y - 2x - z &= 3\\z - y &=1\end{align}$$

could you figure it out, then?